# Migradoc Superscript

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm trying  to use native migradoc supercript with formatedText but however the supercripted text is too small  in size. When i try to increase the size of the FormatedText, it doesn't behave like expected. I'm using Pre-Release version 1.5 beta3 of [PdfSharp-Migradoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net/Preview_Information.ashx)

here is my sample code :

```
       //Build Pdf Document 
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument();

        //Build PDF Page
        PdfPage pdfpage = pdfDoc.AddPage();

        //Build Graphics
        XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfpage);

        //Build Migradoc 
        Document migradoc = new Document();

        //add Migra doc Section
        Section sec = migradoc.AddSection();
        //camp dates
        Paragraph campDatesPara = sec.AddParagraph();

        campDatesPara.AddText(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd"));
        FormattedText ft = campDatesPara.AddFormattedText("st");
        //ft.Size = 10;//for size testing
        ft.Superscript = true;
```

Html Sample of Results & Expected results [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDXGN4SESPND)

Comment: You write "it doesn't behave like expected" but you don't show what happens and you don't write what you expect.

Comment: I was expecting a normal superscript   like in a word document or HTML : `<p>A<sup>2</sup></p>`  or [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_sup)

Comment: You don't show what you get. In our documents it looks like normal superscript, e.g. from Word.

Comment: @User241.007 please check  the sample example

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the size of the Superscript text will also move it higher. This is what has to be expected.

With MigraDoc there is no option to explicitly set the size of the superscript text. The size of the superscript is about 60 or 70% (guess without checking the source code) of the size you set for the formatted text. This is by design.

A slight increase should be possible without moving it too far upwards.

Comment: Superscript works as the makers of MigraDoc expect it to work. MigraDoc is open source and you can implement the superscript you want, either changing the current attribute or implementing a new one. Or maybe use PDFsharp and `XGraphics.DrawString` to create the effect you need.